# Is it possible to run queries with init scripts through properties in HSQL?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

Just wanted to understand if its possible to run init scripts through HSQL properties we are supplying along with connection in HSQL? Is that feature available in HSQL, like we do a init and execute sql queries in H2 along with properties when connection is established?

Answer (score 1):

Not on the connection URL.

You can run the the init script using HSQLDB's SqlTool in your application.

See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#sqltool_nonint-sect